# Return results where a value does not exist

Tags: mysql

Good afternoon! Please let me preface my question by pointing out that I am very much inexperienced with MySQL but am being forced to learn. That said, I have a table with the below structure:

[image: Table View]

The issue I face is that the ExtraFieldID's for 498 and 499 don't exist for each ID listed. I need to figure out how to find the ID's that are missing those ExtraFieldID values but not return the other results. How could I go about doing this?
 Thus far, I either haven't found the solution or don't yet have the skill to recognize the solution. 
Either way, it's still a problem for me.

I appreciate any help that anyone is able to provide.

Comment: Can you clarify your question further?  What do you mean that don't exist for each Id listed?

Comment: So im guessing you want ID's who doesn't have `498 and 499` ExtraFieldID?

Comment: Sure. This particular table contains values referenced by other tables for an RMM tool. For example, ExtraFieldID 498 refers to a checkbox on the frontend for the database. The ID column could refer to a specific client, a specific location for the client, or a specific computer with the monitoring agent installed. For the purpose of this post, the ID column references the location ID on another table. If the checkbox has never been altered, the 498 value under the ExtraFieldID column will not exist for the corresponding ID. I need to find the ID values missing the corresponding 498 value.

Comment: can you provide some samples

Answer (score 0):

This will find all the IDs that don't have `ExtraFieldId = 498`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM yourTable
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE ExtraFieldId = 498)
```

Or you can use a self-JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id
FROM yourTable AS t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t2.ExtraFieldId = 498
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to return records (or just the IDs?) you can use the combination of `WHERE` and `NOT IN` clause - to check for both `498` and `499`. You could write a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT yourTable.id FROM yourTable WHERE ExtraFieldID NOT IN (498, 499);
```

I hope this helps.